# Reducing number of relationships in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship, data-modeling

My app comes with an extensive data model created in Core Data. As the model grows I find that I’m creating loads of optional relationships, and it looks more messy and bloated than I feel it should be. **Is there a proper way to reduce the number of relationships?**

In general, the main driver of the numerous relationships is that I have many entities that require some specific properties, depending on the entities morphology. I've sketched a hypothetical example to create some context. Imagine in the app the user can create animals. Each animal has some general properties, but depending on which animal we are dealing with, there are also a number of specific properties. **My current approach would lead to a model where an animal entity has several one-to-one relationships to specified property entities as in the model below.**

[image]

However, **clearly the number of relationships gets out of hand easily as you want to grow this model**. Plus there is nothing that stops the current animal from erroneously getting assigned more than one specified property entity. **I’m thinking of switching to an alternative where I remove the core data relationship and use UIDs to match an animal with the specific properties as drawn below**. The animal entity gets a “specifiedProps” attribute where I store a UID that links to one of the specifiedProperty entities that each get a UID attribute.

[image]

For as far as I can oversee this has the following downsides and benefits

Downsides:

- It requires some overhead that normally gets dealt with by Core Data (like cascading deletion),
- Fetching will be a little slower, but only one specified property entity will have to fetched per animal so I think this should not be an issue.

Benefits:

- Reduce the ever growing number of optional relationships in my app and save on storage as the user creates more and more animals.
- An animal clearly has only one set off specified properties.
- Easier migration; when introducing new animals no relationships have to be created, just a new entity.

My question is whether I’m overlooking something? Am I making a terrible mistake, or, perhaps, there is a better alternative?

Any comment critique would be much appreciated.

Ps. I’m aware that Core Data allows for parent/child entities, but as far as I understand, with an sqlite store behind it, each attribute of a specified entity for each animal will end up in one table. This seems highly undesirable, considering in my case each Animal has a list of specific properties and in the future the number of animals should be allowed to grow to large numbers as well.

Comment: Have you considered using entity inheritance instead? Make Cat, Snake, etc sub-entities of Animal instead of separate entities.

Comment: @TomHarrington I have considered it. From a modelling perspective it's the cleanest option. But as I understand the underlying store will use a table containing all the attributes of the super and sub-entities and therefore it's not a desirable option when you consider I have some 5 sub-entities that each have 10 attributes.

Comment: As an alternative, could you create a generic “AnimalProperty” entity, with attributes such as “propertyName” (possible values being “furType”, “beakWidth”, etc), “propertyType” (“int”, “float”, “string”, etc), and “propertyValue”.  Then have a to-many relationship from Animal to AnimalProperty.  You could add an “animalType” attribute to Animal, and would need meta-data to indicate which animalProperties were appropriate for each animalType (eg. Cat = {furType, tailLength}).  Messy, but a simpler model at the expense of a more complicated code base.

Comment: @pbasdf that would definitely reduce the complexity of the model by a lot. How would you type the propertyValue attribute? Use transformable, binary data, or have a field for each of the types?

Comment: Personally I think I would use a string representation, which should be straight forward to convert for simple ints, floats and strings.  It might also help for fetch predicates (transformables and binary data cannot easily be used to filter a fetch).

Comment: @pbasdf sounds like a good suggestion. I'll have to read up a bit on the storage size aspects of it ("animal" instances are abundant and properties are mainly Int16), but I think it's the best solution. Once properties became more numerous I already refactored my code to pass individual properties around as (propType, propValue) so otherwise the conversion should be quite straight forward. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach I have rested on so far, in case it helps anyone (feel free to critique).

I created a generic property entity as suggested by @pbasdf. Converted into the animal analogy the model comes out like this.

[image]

Each animal has a one-to-many relationship ("properties") to Property. Property holds both a type (Int16) and a value (Binary Data). Based on the type the binary value gets converted into Float, String, UIColor or whatever data-type matches the property-type.

Initially I defined value as a String, but during the switch I noticed a considerable performance decrease. In the original model properties were specifically defined. As such they could be accessed directly and were provided in the correct type. With the new setup, however, two extra steps are required. 1) Based on the type we have to find the correct property first. There are typically less than 10 for an instance of animal, but on average it still means a couple have to be evaluated before the correct one is found. 2) Converting from the generic value to the correct datatype adds time as well. The two steps caused a considerable increase in property fetching times when using Strings (10+). By using a binary attribute to store the value the increase was limited to 3-4 times. Of course if you have a need to search the value, Strings are more accessible as mentioned by pbasdf.

Finally I have the issue that the Animal entity still belongs to several containers, meaning a considerable amount of incoming relationships that clutter the model. Unfortunately in my model I'm not dealing with Animals and cannot just convert Jungle, Zoo and WildLifePreserve into a generic Enclosure entity. Rather Animal is a general property container that provides properties for a whole range of different entities.